# Dialogue Fragment causing Android application to crash when attempting to save after configuration change

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have two classes, a `Fragment` and a `DialogFragment`. The code works when you keep the device in either portrait or landscape throughout the process, however when you open the dialogue and change the rotation configuration the application crashes in CustomDatePicker.class on the line;

`listener.onDateComplete();`

Obviously this is because the reference was dropped due to lifecycle events and the Activity being recreated while doing so.

I've read that I can handle configuration changes manually and remove the events that cause the activity to be recreated on configuration changes, however i feel this could cause problems later and id rather allow androids to handle these events.

Is there any other way around this?

User.class;

```
public class User extends Fragment {

UserAdapter adapter;

public User() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.basic_list, container, false);

    adapter = new UserAdapter(Providers.getUserItems(), inflater);

    ListView lv = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listview);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            switch (Providers.getUserItems().get(position)) {
                case DOB:
                    dob();
                    break;
                case HEIGHT:
                    break;
                case NAME:
                    break;
                case GENDER:
                    break;
                case LOCATION:
                    break;
                case ETHNICITY:
                    break;
                case CONDITION:
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    });

    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    return v;
}


private void dob() {
    CustomDatePicker customDatePicker = new CustomDatePicker();
    customDatePicker.setListener(new CustomDatePicker.DateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateComplete() {
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
    customDatePicker.setCancelable(false);
    customDatePicker.show(getFragmentManager(), CustomDatePicker.EXTRA_DATE);
}


}
```

and CustomDatePicker.class;

```
public class CustomDatePicker extends DialogFragment {

public static final String EXTRA_DATE = "EXTRA_DATE";

//private DatePicker mDatePicker;
private View v;
private DateListener listener;

public static CustomDatePicker newInstance(Date date) {
    CustomDatePicker datePickerFragment = new CustomDatePicker();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putSerializable(EXTRA_DATE, date);
    datePickerFragment.setArguments(args);
    return datePickerFragment;
}

public CustomDatePicker() {
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.date_picker, container, false);

    DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) v.findViewById(R.id.date_picker);

    Preferences prefs = new Preferences(getActivity());

    TimeController timeController = prefs.getDob();

    datePicker.updateDate(timeController.getZonetime().getYear(), timeController.getZonetime().getMonthValue() - 1, timeController.getZonetime().getDayOfMonth());

    Button btnSave = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.save);
    btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getDate();
            dismiss();
            listener.onDateComplete();
        }
    });

    Button btnCancel = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
    btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dismiss();
        }
    });

    return v;
}

private void getDate() {
    DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) v.findViewById(R.id.date_picker);

    TimeController timeController = new TimeController(TimeZones.NONEFALSE);
    timeController.set(datePicker.getYear(), datePicker.getMonth() + 1, datePicker.getDayOfMonth(), 0, 0, 0, 0);

    Preferences prefs = new Preferences(getActivity());
    prefs.setDob(timeController);
}

public void setListener(DateListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}

public interface DateListener {
    void onDateComplete();
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just reset your listener after recreation, add this to your `User` fragment:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    CustomDatePicker fragment = (CustomDatePicker)getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(CustomDatePicker.EXTRA_DATE);
    if (fragment != null){
       fragment.setListener(new CustomDatePicker.DateListener() {
          @Override
          public void onDateComplete() {
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
          }
       });
    }
}
```

Your `CustomDatePicker` will lose reference to that listener as you said.  After configuration changed (orientation for example), your `CustomDatePicker` is recreated and added to FragmentManager with the same tag you have used to show the dialog, so all you need to do is to find that instance of your dialog frament (`onActivityCreated` is one of the methods you can use - it's called right before `onStart`) and set that listener again.

Comment: It works, but I don't understand why. Could you explain a little whats going on?